# Couchbase - Creating new property in all document types Foo where its value is taken from document type Bar?

Tags: couchbase, bulkupdate, database, nosql

```
Foo: {
 id: 100,
 barId: 123, 
 startDate: "12/12/79", //new field to be added 
} ,    

Bar: { 
 id: 123,
 startDate: "12/12/79",
}
```

We need to create a new property 'startDate' in all document types 'Foo' that its value is taken from document type 'Bar'.

All 'Foo' documents contain a "foreign key" to Bar (a field called 'BarId').

What is the easiest way to do it besides retrieving and updating all entities programmatically  ?
(Couchbase version is 3.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UPDATE` didn't quite work for me since I need to perform some sort of a "join" between 2 document types. But it looks like Couchbase's `MERGE` statement is just what I needed.

http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/merge.html

We'll upgrade to 4.1 and see how it goes.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you mean some declarative solution resembling SQL UPDATE. Such a thing isn't available for CB 3, but since CB 4.1, N1QL has an UPDATE statement. Check http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.1/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/update.html.

Answer (score 4):

As TAM said, you could probably do that with UPDATE statement from `N1QL` in Couchbase 4.1... but you're using 3.0.

In Couchbase 3.x, your best best is to write:

1. a `view` that will allow you to get IDs of all documents of type `Foo`
2. a script that uses a SDK to:

   1. query that view
   2. retrieve each `Foo` doc
   3. get the `Bar` id from the content of the `Foo` doc
   4. fetch the `Bar` doc
   5. update the `Foo` content accordingly and save (update) the `Foor` document in db

Comment: By the way, as CB, due to its schemaless philosophy, doesn't have all those snug maintenance tools like phpmyadmin or pgadmin, you will soon need algorithms like this anyway.